# Prove that function has no finite limit using $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I want to prove using
$$(\exists \varepsilon  > 0)(\forall \delta  > 0)\exists x(0 < \left| {x - {x_0}} \right| < \delta  \Rightarrow \left| {f(x) - L} \right| \ge \varepsilon )$$
That the function $$f(x) = {x \over {\left( {x - \left\lfloor {\sin x} \right\rfloor } \right)}}$$ has no finite limit when $x_0 = 0$
and I can't seem to find the way to start.
I know using the heine method that the function has 1 and 0 limits on both sides, so I'm guessing that if i choose an $\varepsilon=1/2 $ I might be able to show that, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Why do you think this function has no finite limit as $x \to 0$? $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x+\sin(x)}$ exists and is finite.

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong, fixed it now

Comment: Hint. What is the value of $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$ when $x$ is close to $0$. (It doesn't even have to be very close).

Comment: When it's 0- it's -1 and when it's 0+ it's 0, I still don't understand how to use it formally

Comment: Further hint. Given what you know you should be able to draw the graph of the function near $0$. That might suggest a value of $\epsilon$ for which there is no $\delta$.

Comment: It's just that I don't understand how this could be proven with just one point on the graph, I mean let there be an x and an f(x) for it, who knows if L isn't exactly that f(x)?
It's obvious when using two points, I just don't see how it could be done with one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You need to show that, for each $L \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ with the property you mentioned.

Suggestion: Take $\varepsilon = 1/3$. For $L \geq 1/2$, consider points $-\delta < x < 0$; for $L \leq 1/2$, consider points $0 < x < \delta$.